# VOLTDB ERROR: SQL ERROR More than 100 MB of temp table memory used while executing SQL

Tags: sql, database, voltdb

I'm getting this error while querying a 10,000,000 database in VoltDB. Any idea on how to get around it?

> VOLTDB ERROR: SQL ERROR
>   More than 100 MB of temp table memory used while executing SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the temp table memory in your configuration file. It is 100 MB by default. See the temp table section of the docs here for more information: https://docs.voltdb.com/AdminGuide/HostConfigDBOpts.php

Full Disclosure: I work at VoltDB.

Comment: Thank you!
Now I'm getting this error... any ideas on how to set a different limit ? 
Output from SQL stmt overflowed output/network buffer of 50mb

Comment: There's a hard 50mb limit on messages to or from VoltDB. It's not clear what you are trying to do, but whatever it is needs to be redesigned.

Comment: I'm trying to select * from table...I want to do a complicated query (I know), but it's for research in IMDB performance.
Is there any way of setting a different limit?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The limit is hard coded and cannot be changed.